# GNOME alternatives / equivalent for Klipper?

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard-manager

Anyone has any tool, other than a pen and pencil to help me manage more than 5 "copy-pastes"? I heard of Glipper, but anymore, with a small description and pros/cons would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have:

Glipper - Klipper's Brother... for GTK. It has a limited amount of entries (MAX 99 Vs Klipper with 1024) but has nice features like sync different Glippers in the network, smart detection for similar clipboard copies and others. After a couple of versions ago, Glipper is GONE!. What you can do in Ubuntu 18.04+ is install the Gnome Extension Clipboard Indicator here https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/

Parcellite - Small clipboard manager. Very nice and simple.

Synergy - You can share clipboard over Network (Including Mouse and Keyboard)

xfce4-clipman / xfce4-clipman-plugin - Klipper's Smaller Brother.. for xfce.

Install by:

```
sudo apt-get install glipper

sudo apt-get install parcellite

sudo apt-get install synergy

sudo apt-get install xfce4-clipman
```

Comment: `glipper` doesn't seem to be available in `bionic`?

Comment: Thank you @JamesHirschorn I updated to include the Clipboard Indicator.

Answer (score 9):

Try Clipit

[image: clipit screenshot]

Install via Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install clipit
```

Answer (score 7):

**[Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon)**

[image: diodon screenshot]

Install by using the PPA via Terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:diodon-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install diodon diodon-plugins
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Diodon is no longer functional on Ubuntu 15.04. I believe the last release in which it work correctly was 14.04.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Works fine now

Comment: @LuísdeSousa was announced here https://esite.ch/2015/07/using-custom-shortcuts-of-de-as-diodon-hotkey/ and you can see that now, you setup a custom key shortcut for Diodon in Unity and Gnome Shell, was a different way to work for Diodon, not an incompatibility in newer Ubuntu releases

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is no longer supported, I will only test a new Diodon version when Ubuntu 16.04 is released.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend **[Pastie](https://github.com/fmoralesc/pastie)**.

[image: pastie screenshot]

Install it by -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hel-sheep/pastie

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pastie
```

Comment: Pastie seems to be discontinued now

Answer (score 6):

> [CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) is a clipboard manager written in Qt that comes with some advanced features, image support, editable history, command line support, keyboard shortcuts and more.

[image: CopQ indicator]

**CopyQ features:**

- configurable history size, number of tray menu items, etc.;
- editable and searchable clipboard history;
- keyboard shortcuts for opening the clipboard history, show the tray menu and more;
- commands: you can define actions or commands when a text copied to the clipboard matches some criteria you set. This can be used for instance to open video player if text copied to the clipboard is an URL with multimedia content and so on;
- image support: when you copy a selection in GIMP, an image in Shutter (take a screenshot), etc., the image preview is displayed in the tray menu as well as in the clipboard history. This obviously doesn't work if you copy some image file (e.g.: in Nautilus) since that's treated like any other file;
- command line support: tabs, items, clipboard and configuration can be changed through command line interface;
- more.

[image: CopQ clipboard view]
[image: CopQ Configuration windows]

Also, since the application is written in Qt, the tray icon/menu is automatically converted to an AppIndicator so you can use CopyQ in Unity without having to whitelist it to be able to use the notification area. If you don't get an AppIndicator for CopyQ, install the "sni-qt" package.

Ubuntu 13.04, 12.10 and 12.04 users can install CopyQ by using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samrog131/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install copyq
```

Since the above PPA has quite a few packages which might **not be stable**, I suggest you remove the PPA after installing CopyQ:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:samrog131/ppa
```

**Source:** [Webupd8.org - CopyQ: Interesting Clipboard Manager With Advanced Features](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/copyq-interesting-clipboard-manager.html)

Comment: Can anyone comment on performance, since "lightweight" seems to be the most commonly occuring word in the descriptions of the alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

Try [**Parcellite**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/parcellite)

[image: parcellite screenshot]!

It's in the Ubuntu repo:

```
sudo apt-get install parcellite
```

Parcellite is a stripped down, basic-features-only clipboard manager
with a small memory footprint for those who like simplicity.

Features:

- Keeps a clipboard history.
- Various view options to display items the way you like it.
- Daemon mode; guard your clipboard contents when you close applications.
- Perform custom commands using clipboard contents.

Answer (score 0):

Parcellite now supports unity, and there's a ppa for the latest releases. There are two ppas - one that supports Unity and one that does not (for older distros or minimal systems).
The Unity ppa is https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/parcellite-appindicator

The NON-Unity ppa is https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/parcellite

The latest code is: http://parcellite.sourceforge.net

Comment: these builds are outdated

Comment: True - Parcellite seems to be getting pulled into all mainstream distros, so I haven't kept up with the latest Ubuntu releases.