# How to install Klipper? What would you suggest instead if the package is not anymore available?

Tags: 20.04, productivity

How to install Klipper? The package is referred here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Klipper

Running `sudo apt install klipper` results in E: Package 'klipper' has no installation candidate. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4. If this was the correct way to *try to install the package* but the package is not anymore available, what would you recommend to use instead?

I have been using Mac and Jumpcut for years and I am looking something that would do the same job in Ubuntu.

Comment: Klipper exists & is installed by default in a modern release of Kubuntu - it's included as part of `plasma-workspace` and does **not** require a separate installed package  (*Thanks to Rik Mills (developer) for this comment*)

Comment: Thanks! So I suppose I could also somehow install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: It's part of the Plasma desktop; ie. KDE as used by Kubuntu; thus won't help if you're using GNOME (ie. Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS).  I'd suggest concentrating your question looking for alternatives for your chosen GNOME desktop.  (I'm using LXQt/Lubuntu sorry; so my desktop uses `qlipper`)

Comment: Ok, I see. If you modify your comment to be an answer I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Klipper exists & is installed by default in a modern release of Kubuntu - it's included as part of `plasma-workspace` and does not require a separate installed package

*That (^) knowledge is from Rik Mills (*developer*)*

Being part of the Plasma desktop, it's included by default on any Kubuntu install as used by KDE, but this won't help you if you're using GNOME (ie. Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS).

I'd suggest concentrating your question looking for *alternatives* for your chosen GNOME desktop. (eg. I'm using LXQt/Lubuntu; so my desktop uses `qlipper`)

FYI:   `klipper` was separated into its own package *last* in `trusty` or 14.04 LTS

`klipper | 4:4.11.11-0ubuntu0.2 | trusty-updates/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el`

Comment: I went for https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/ suggested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/19370/gnome-alternatives-equivalent-for-klipper. Seems to do a fairly decent job, although not as handy as Jumpcut IMHO.